# Xamarin.Forms IOS move xcassets folder

Tags: xamarin.forms, resources, xcasset

Until a few days ago in my iOS project the `Media.xcassets` folder was under the
`Resources` folder.

Now is under the `root` of the application and if I try to move no one of the images are showed.

It's possible to move this folder under the `Resoures` folder like before?

Thank you.

**EDIT:**

This is my Info.plist file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
    <array>
      <integer>1</integer>
      <integer>2</integer>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
      <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
      <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
      <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
      <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
      <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
      <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
      <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
      <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>MinimumOSVersion</key>
    <string>10.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>SgatMobileV2</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>it.volos.SgatMobile</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
    <array>
      <string>Icon-60@2x</string>
      <string>Icon-60@3x</string>
      <string>Icon-76</string>
      <string>Icon-76@2x</string>
      <string>Default</string>
      <string>Default@2x</string>
      <string>Default-568h@2x</string>
      <string>Default-Portrait</string>
      <string>Default-Portrait@2x</string>
      <string>Icon-Small-40</string>
      <string>Icon-Small-40@2x</string>
      <string>Icon-Small-40@3x</string>
      <string>Icon-Small</string>
      <string>Icon-Small@2x</string>
      <string>Icon-Small@3x</string>
    </array>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>XSAppIconAssets</key>
    <string>Resources/Media.xcassets/AppIcons.appiconset</string>
    <key>XSLaunchImageAssets</key>
    <string>Resources/Media.xcassets/LaunchImages.launchimage</string>
    <key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
    <array>
    </array>
    <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This app needs access to the camera to take photos.</string>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This app needs access to photos.</string>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This app needs access to the photo gallery.</string>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Sure, just make sure the paths are updated in your `info.plist` file

Comment: @GeraldVersluis Thank you. I have added my Info.plist file. Where is the path that you have talked about? Thank you!